# Fallo sobre el emento Snap

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentado referenciar el elemento Toledo de mi svg para que cambie de color pero me dice que Snap no se encuentra no se que podria ser.

SVG

https://justpaste.it/4m7mw

CODIGO JS

```
        var s = Snap("#canvas");
        var Toledo = s.select("#Toledo");
        Toledo.attr({
        fill: "cyan"
        }).click(function() {
        var selected = Toledo.data("selected");
        Toledo.attr({
            fill: (selected) ? "green" : "cyan"
        });
        Toledo.data("selected", !selected);
        });
```

Comment: ¿ya lo tienes instalado? Veo que se puede descargar aqui: https://github.com/adobe-webplatform/Snap.svg/archive/v0.5.1.zip o bien en github https://github.com/adobe-webplatform/Snap.svg

Comment: he importado las librerías pero sigue saliendo error.   https://justpaste.it/2q42j